# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Tags: jquery-ui

I can't seem to show a datepicker from jQuery UI on a **hidden field** as I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
```

When I use a regular text field, I don't seem to have a problem. I get this error with both `jQuery UI 1.9.0` and `1.9.2`, the version of `jQuery is 1.8.3`

html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <small class="date_target">until <span>Dec. 31, 2013</span></small>
            <input type="hidden" class="end_date" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(".end_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-yy',
    yearRange: '-00:+01'
});

$('.date_target').click(function () {
    $(this).next().datepicker('show');
});
```

I provided a (not) working example on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jghyllebert/arht8/) too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because the input field is not visible to the browser (because it's hidden).

Try this:

```
<input type="text" style="height: 0px; width:0px; border: 0px;" class="end_date" />
```

and you are fine. Of course, you can add the extra style attributes to the CSS class "end_date". A "display:none" will not help, because then the field is fully invisible again.

Example also in a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucUM5/1/).

Comment: Thanks. I had to use some extra css, but it helped.

Answer (score 7):

Let's check datepicker _findPos function

```
$.datepicker._findPos = function (obj) {
        var position,
            inst = this._getInst(obj),
            isRTL = this._get(inst, "isRTL");

        while (obj && (obj.type === "hidden" || obj.nodeType !== 1 || $.expr.filters.visible(obj))) {
            obj = obj[isRTL ? "previousSibling" : "nextSibling"];
        }

        position = $(obj).offset();        

        /*because position of invisible element is null, js will break on next line*/
        return [position.left, position.top]; 
    };
```

If target obj of datepicker is invisible, it will use the closest sibling position which is not invisible

There are several solutions：

**Solution 1**

Because of LTR, you can exchange position of two element

```
<tr>
    <td> 
        <input type="hidden" class="end_date" />
        <small class="date_target">until <span>Dec. 31, 2013</span></small>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Solution 2**

Add an visible element next to the hidden element, so datepicker will find the visible element position

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <small class="date_target">until <span>Dec. 31, 2013</span></small>
        <input type="hidden" class="end_date" /><span>&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Solution 3**

Redefine _findPos function, so you can set position of calendar wherever you want

```
$.datepicker._findPos = function (obj) {
        var position,
            inst = this._getInst(obj),
            isRTL = this._get(inst, "isRTL");

        while (obj && (obj.type === "hidden" || obj.nodeType !== 1 || $.expr.filters.visible(obj))) {
            obj = obj[isRTL ? "previousSibling" : "nextSibling"];
        }

        position = $(obj).offset();
        // if element type isn't hidden, use show and hide to find offset
        if (!position) { position = $(obj).show().offset(); $(obj).hide();}
        // or set position manually
        if (!position) position = {left: 999, top:999};
        return [position.left, position.top]; 
    };
```

Comment: This answer was actually more helpful to me than the accepted one.  Even after changing the styles of the element to 'appear' hidden, it was still giving me the error *unless* I gave it an actual width/height.  However, putting my dynamically-added hidden field at the beginning of the document instead of the end solves it :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while using Bootstrap as well, cause I needed my datepicker to show with a button click.

**This works:**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="sr-only" for="txtDate">Date</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="display: none;" id="txtDate">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btnDate">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Calendar
   </button>
</div>
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="sr-only" for="txtDate">Date</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="display: none;" id="txtDate">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btnDate">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Calendar
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#txtDate').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
   showAnim: 'fade'
});
$("#btnDate").on('click', function(){
   $('#txtDate').datepicker('show');
});
```

So all I needed was to put the button on the same div element. In case anyone else has this problem.

Comment: don't use `style="display: none;"` of form elements you plan to submit values to server