# HTML/CSS Only: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS to try to create a background-like image, but without linking the image in CSS.  When I try to load it in Chrome I get a console error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined.

My `html.erb` code is:

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <%= image_tag 'bg-hero-000.jpg', class: "main-image" %>
</div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
.main-image {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .main-image {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
  }
}
```

Can anyone see why I'm getting this error or how to fix it?

Comment: This may be Javascript error, not CSS. look once, it may help you. :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105595/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-left-of-undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105595/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-left-of-undefined)

Comment: I saw this post initially, but there isn't any javascript on the page, and nothing is marked as hidden.

Comment: Could you clarify the context in which you are using this? It seems as though what you're trying to do is not HTML and CSS only. You're using `<%=` and `%>` which are tags used by JavaScript templating included in libraries like underscore.js, lodash.js or ejs.

Comment: Ah, its an `html.erb` document.  That's just using Ruby to link the image.  It renders the same as if it were html...

Comment: @Liz: That error is definitely not a CSS or HTML error. You should be having some JS or something which is trying to read the `left` property of an element that doesn't exist. Does the console not say which file and line number (on the right side)?

Comment: It just says VM30111:304 and when I hover over that link it says `debugger:///VM30111:304`.

Comment: @Liz, does removing your content still throw this error? And have you tested this page in an incognito window with no chrome extensions?

Comment: Ahhh, the error does go away when the content is removed!  What does that mean...?

Comment: Do you have a public URL of your project? So we could help you to debug,